# Why is updatedTransactions never called?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase

After the user purchase the item, by entering email and password and paying, the method updatedTransactions is never called. The item is regularly bought but, without calling updatedTransactions methor I can't execute the code to add the item to the app. I noticed that the item is bought because if I run the code to restore an item bought, everything goes fine and the product gets installed into the app.

Here is the code I copied to buy the product:

```
-(IBAction)buyProduct:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Purchasing: %@", self.product.productIdentifier);

    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:self.product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

}
```

Follows the code to restore the product:

```
-(IBAction)restoreProduct:(id)sender {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

I noticed that in this last piece of code I have the following line:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
```

Should I add this line in the buy part too?

Comment: Check out the StoreKitSuite sample by apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc1991/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding the following code in the buyProduct method:

```
-(IBAction)buyProduct:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Purchasing: %@", self.product.productIdentifier);

    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:self.product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self]; //added line
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

}
```

Now the method updatedTransactions is called before making the payment and after the payment.

With the following code you can check if everything went good or bad:

```
for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        if (transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased) {
            [self unlockRemoveiAD];
            [OKalertView show];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
        }

        if (transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed) {
            [alertView show];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should addTransactionObserver as soon as possible, best place for this is App delegate method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: @TimurSuleimanov What if I add the observer later such as after my app intro video finish?

Comment: @jayatubi Then it's possible, that Apple will send you a transaction, but you won't receive it, because you didn't add an observer, so you won't handle user's transaction. It can be auto-renewable subscription transaction, not sure, but possible, cancel transaction(when user canceled purchase) or restore in-app purchase transaction.